# Как быстро найти фрагмент изображения на огромной картинке?

Tags: php, c, golang, изображения, opencv

Две картинки, обе в PNG. Одна небольшая, вторая огромная. Как быстро найти все места, где на большой картинке есть мелкая?

Т.к. формат изображения без потери качества, то сравнивать можно пиксель-в-пиксель. И просто двигать "окно" размером с мелкую картинку по всей большой. Считать степень расхождения и потом оставлять самые подходящие участки.

Но это невероятно медленно и долго, если большая фотка - UltraHD (3840×2160), а мелкая, например, 100 на 100 точек.

OpenCV и прочие либы ищут не особо быстро. Я бы даже согласился на нечёткий поиск, если он будет приемлемой точности и шустрый (1-2 секунды максимум). Соглашусь и на предварительную обработку большой фотки т.к. флоу работы с ней это позволяет сделать и за бОльшее время, и просто хранить неоригинальную, а подготовленную версию.

Решение ищу на любом языке, если бинарик можно запускать как самостоятельное консольное приложение. Или же на старом добром php (но в это верится с трудом).

UPD.:

переписал версию с php

https://gist.github.com/Lexx918/c0327c1262a837de0e7cc99bfded131b

на golang

https://gist.github.com/Lexx918/3b1f57e3da19f6e69ead39021e3a24a6

прирост скорости такой, что задумался, а нужны ли ещё оптимизации?!

Comment: В любом случае нужно пробежаться по всей картинке. Я бы брал первые байт 8 (или 4, нужно подумать) мелкого изображения и искал их. И только если они найдены, тогда сравнивать всю картинку. Большую картинку можно разделить на 4-8 кусков и разбросать по ядрам (само изображение даже не нужно делить).

Comment: @KoVadim если рубить на куски, то есть вероятность попасть границей такого куска как раз по подходящему участку, и это провал (

Comment: Смотря что ищите. Если вы ищете обьект большого размера - то можно искать с шагом в размер или половину размера большого обьекта. Например если я хочу найти большие квадратные белые области 100x100 то я могу пройти изображение с шагом 100.

Comment: а не нужно физически разбивать изображение. просто указатели в нужно место. И граница корректно обработается

Comment: двигаться с шагом или по областям тоже не выйдет т.к. можно напороться на вырожденный случай шага и нужная область окажется аккурат между шагами

Comment: я ещё пробовал вариант уменьшить изображения, найти области на мелких, а потом смаштабировать обратно на оригиналы и поискать уже только в более менее подходящих. но изменение размеров даёт столько артефактов, что иногда они приводят к совсем неверному результату.

Comment: что значит "огромная"? Какие размеры? 8192x4320? [`matchTemplate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14417703/4279) или [`minMaxLoc()`](https://github.com/Qarj/search-image/blob/509f27fe99e7916536ae70425b05a5fad2878837/search-image.py) достаточно быстро работают? Ещё [`imagemagick compare -subimage-search`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#subimage-search) Связанный вопрос [Image in Image Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4720168/4279)

Comment: @jfs размеры указаны в самом вопросе. imagemagick пробовал, ищет минуты 3-4 :) мой велосипед на пыхе справляется на порядок быстрее.

Comment: @jfs попробую рецепт из ответа в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720168/image-in-image-algorithm такого ещё не было. спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Насколько помню, в OpenCV для поиска фрагмента на картинке реализована корреляционная функция. Довольно трудоемкий алгоритм, есть отличная замена - алгоритм Mean Absolute Difference (MAD). По сути, обычный модуль разности. Вроде бы именно он в TERCOMе используется, например.
Кроме того, для повышения быстродействия можно воспользоваться прореживанием, то есть не обязательно сравнивать/считать корреляцию каждого пикселя основного изображения и маленького, можно "проредить" как основное, так и маленькое изображение. Как минимум через 1 столбец можно смело проскакивать. Можно и больше, но, главное, чтобы эталонное изображение не потеряло своей отличительной черты.
Есть еще способ - так называемое введение порога. Такой порог позволяет практически по нескольким пикселям сразу понять, соответствует ли фрагмент искомому или же нет. 
Положение маленького изображения на большом будет характеризоваться минимумом (в случае использования самой обычной корреляционной функции) или же максимумом (если использовать MAD). Если ваши изображения не зашумлены никак, то корреляция в том месте, где находится искомый объект, будет 0 (в случае MAD). Значит, если при расчете корреляции встретили что-то отличное от 0, то можно смело двигаться дальше. При наличии шума придется порог поправять на этот шум.
В теории, можно совмещать все методы и получить очень значительное ускорение. А вообще, использование одного лишь порога дает очень и очень существенный буст.

Нашел у себя код на С++ с OpenCV для корреляционного поля с использованием порога вот. На вход основное изображение и шаблон, который ищем, на выход - корреляционная карта. Потом просто по карте ищется минимум.

```
void meanAbsuluteDifference_LIM(const Mat &_img, const Mat &_templ, Mat &_res){
    int M = _res.rows,
        N = _res.cols,
        m = _templ.rows,
        n = _templ.cols;

    register float RES_ELEM = 0, TEMP_ELEM = 0;
    register int   I = 0, J = 0, i = 0, j = 0;

    for (I; I < M; ++I){
        for (J; J < N; ++J){
            RES_ELEM = 0;
            lim = 0;
            for (i; i < m; ++i){
                for (j; j < n; ++j){
                    uchar RI = _img.at<uchar>(I + i, J + j),
                        CI = _templ.at<uchar>(i, j);
                    RES_ELEM += std::abs(RI - CI);
                    lim += stdDevNoise;  // поправка порога на ско шума. шума нет - порог всегда 0.
                    if (RES_ELEM > lim){ // получили значение больше порога - останавливаем проверку и двигаемся дальше
                        goto stop;
                    }
                }
            }
        stop:
            i = 0; j = 0;
            _res.at<float>(I, J) += RES_ELEM;
        }
        J = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: прореживание ещё не пробовал, спасибо. а вот MAD по ходу я уже изобрёл и так. считаю модуль разности каждого цвета каждого пикселя каждой подходящей области в большой фотке по размеру мелкой. чем меньше разница, тем больше уровень схожести.

Comment: с mad ещё проблема - вырожденный случай, когда пиксель с отличием находится в конце последовательности. и приходится посчитать суммы для всех предшествующих пикселей (а там сумма будет равна 0) пока не встретим первое отличие. печаль

Comment: Откопал свой код для поиска фрагмента на изображении с использованием мэда и пороговой функции и добавил в ответ, правда, только для одноканальных изображений. Но логика, думаю, будет в общем-то та же, только для 3х каналов

Comment: @АлександрБерлускони, Вы хоть язык укажите, на котором функция написана, вдруг пригодится кому (ответ про то, что кто знаком с языком, тот узнает, не пройдет)))

Comment: @АлександрБерлускони да, у меня такое же решение уже есть. выложил тут https://gist.github.com/Lexx918/c0327c1262a837de0e7cc99bfded131b#file-image-pattern-matching-php-L110 вот он модуль разности тут `$result += abs(`. И это дико медленно. + я там пробую ресайз и поиск в мелких копиях

Comment: @Lexx918 пробуйте порог + прореживание тогда. Гляньте эту книжку еще [ссылка](http://www.twirpx.com/file/811134/), в ней есть про ускорение, может что оттуда опробуете