# Рефакторинг 4х вложенных циклов

Tags: java, алгоритм, циклы, инспекция-кода

Есть метод который ищет координаты одного изображения внутри другого. Метод работает, но выглядит ужасно:

```
Point findImgFragment(@NotNull final File subImage, @NotNull final File screenshot) throws IOException {
    final BufferedImage src = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
    final BufferedImage dst = ImageIO.read(subImage);
    //Brute force N^2 check all places in the image.
    for (int i = 0; i <= src.getWidth() - dst.getWidth(); i++) {
        check_subimage:
        for (int j = 0; j <= src.getHeight() - dst.getHeight(); j++) {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < dst.getWidth(); ii++) {
                for (int jj = 0; jj < dst.getHeight(); jj++) {
                    if (dst.getRGB(ii, jj) != src.getRGB(i + ii, j + jj)) {
                        continue check_subimage;
                    }
                }
            }
            //If here, all pixels matched.
            return new Point(i, j);
        }
    }
    return new Point(-1,-1);
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста отрефакторить эти циклы до читаемого состояния. Спасибо.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как быстро найти фрагмент изображения на огромной картинке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/739422/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не менять алгоритм (и если я правильно понял ваш код), то стоит выделить внутренние два цикла в отдельную функцию:

```
Point findImgFragment(
        @NotNull final File subImage,
        @NotNull final File screenshot) throws IOException {

    final BufferedImage src = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
    final BufferedImage dst = ImageIO.read(subImage);
    //Brute force N^2 check all places in the image.
    for (int deltaX = 0; deltaX <= src.getWidth() - dst.getWidth(); deltaX++) {
        for (int deltaY = 0; deltaY <= src.getHeight() - dst.getHeight(); deltaY++) {
            if (findImgFragmentOnOffset(deltaX, deltaY, src, dst)) {
                return new Point(deltaX, deltaY);
            }
        }
    }
    return new Point(-1, -1);
}

boolean findImgFragmentOnOffset(int deltaX, int deltaY,
                                final BufferedImage src, final BufferedImage dst) {
    for (int ii = 0; ii < dst.getWidth(); ii++) {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < dst.getHeight(); jj++) {
            if (dst.getRGB(ii, jj) != src.getRGB(deltaX + ii, deltaY + jj)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    //If here, all pixels matched.
    return true;
}
```

---

Ну вот вам решение со Stream API. Для начала напишем генератор:

```
public static Stream<Point> generateRange(int w, int h) {
    return
        IntStream.range(0, w)
                 .boxed() // какого чёрта IntStream.flatMap возвращает только IntStream??
                 .flatMap(x -> IntStream.range(0, h)
                                        .mapToObj(y -> new Point(x, y)));
}
```

Теперь можно пользоваться:

```
Point findImgFragment(
        @NotNull final File subImage,
        @NotNull final File screenshot) throws IOException {

    final BufferedImage src = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
    final BufferedImage dst = ImageIO.read(subImage);
    //Brute force N^2 check all places in the image.
    Stream<Point> offsets = generateRange(src.getWidth() - dst.getWidth() + 1, // т. к. <=
                                          src.getHeight() - dst.getHeight() + 1);
    return offsets.filter(o -> findImgFragmentOnOffset(o, src, dst))
                  .findFirst()
                  .orElse(new Point(-1, -1));
}
```

Ну и

```
boolean findImgFragmentOnOffset(final Point offset,
                                final BufferedImage src, final BufferedImage dst) {
    return generateRange(dst.getWidth(), dst.getHeight()).allMatch(p ->
        dst.getRGB(p.X, p.Y) == src.getRGB(offset.X + p.X, offset.Y + p.Y));
}
```

Comment: может я не очень удачно выразился, но имел в виду именно избавится хотя-бы от части циклов. Думал может найдется что-нибудь из Stream API... Но все равно спасибо.

Comment: @Pavel: Ну вот вам со Streams API.

Comment: @VladD вместо `.mapToObj(x -> (Integer)x)` достаточно использовать `boxed()`

Comment: @AlexChermenin: Ага, не знал, спасибо!

Comment: @VladD и вместо `+1` для конечного значения при использовании `IntStream.range()` лучше использовать `IntStream.rangeClosed()`

Comment: @AlexChermenin: Тогда пришлось бы использовать `-1` в функции `findImgFragmentOnOffset`. Можно, правда, завести две функции: `generateRange` и `generateRangeClosed`.

Answer (score 3):

Можно не проверять каждую точку в отдельности, а брать целую область. Код в данном случае выглядит лаконичнее, но по сути выполняется то же самое (внутренние циклы просто скрываются):

```
private Point findImgFragment(final File subImage, final File screenshot) throws Exception {
    final BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
    final BufferedImage search = ImageIO.read(subImage);

    // area to search
    int[] searchRGB = search.getRGB(0, 0, search.getWidth(), search.getHeight(), null, 0, search.getWidth());

    for (int i = 0; i <= source.getWidth() - search.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= source.getHeight() - search.getHeight(); j++) {

            // area to check
            int[] sourceRGB = source.getRGB(i, j, search.getWidth(), search.getHeight(), null, 0, search.getWidth());

            // compare the areas
            if (Arrays.equals(searchRGB, sourceRGB)) {
                return new Point(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    return new Point(-1, -1);
}
```

Comment: не выходит из цикла просто бесконечно крутится.

Comment: @Pavel может крутиться долго, но не бесконечно

Comment: тогда получается что при тех же данных деградация производительности в десятки раз если не сотни. До этого тест проходил за 1-2 секунды а тут я секунд 15 ждал и ничего. Не ошибки нет и результата.